# Using throw keyword in a function produces a warning with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, portability, throw

I need to find a way (C++03 please, cant use C++11) to remove a warning produced by gcc on the following (pseudo) code:

```
#include <stdexcept>

void throw_invalid()
{
  throw std::invalid_argument( "invalid" );
}

int foo(const char * str)
{
  if( str ) return 42;
  throw_invalid();
  // insert portable -fake- code that will get optimized away
}
```

My code need to be warning free on at least gcc 5.x (-Wall) and Visual Studio. My `throw_invalid` function is there to avoid boiler plate code, and centralize the exceptions in a single function related to invalid argument.

Currently the warning is:

```
$ g++ -Wall -c foo.cxx 
b.cxx: In function ‘int foo(const char*)’:
b.cxx:13:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

I'd like to avoid adding a fake `return -1` (never reached) since it makes the code harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GCC, you can add the `noreturn` attrubute to the method:

```
void throw_invalid()
#ifdef __GNUC__
    __attribute__ ((noreturn))
#else
    // something here for Visual Studio
#endif
{
  throw std::invalid_argument( "invalid" );
}
```

The manual says:

> The `noreturn` keyword tells the compiler to assume that 'fatal' 
>   cannot return.  It can then optimize without regard to what would 
>   happen if the function ever did return.  This makes slightly better  code. 
>   More importantly, it helps avoid spurious warnings of  uninitialized
>   variables.
>
> The `noreturn` keyword does not affect the exceptional path when 
>   that applies: a `noreturn`-marked function may still return to the 
>   caller by throwing an exception or calling `longjmp`.

I have no experience of your other compiler, so can't fill in the gap there; sorry.

Answer (score 6):

With c++11 you can use the [attribute specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) `[[noreturn]]`.

Like this:

```
[[noreturn]] void throw_invalid()
{
     throw std::invalid_argument( "invalid" );
}

int foo(const char * str)
{
    if( str ) return 42;
    throw_invalid();
    // insert portable -fake- code that will get optimized away
}
```

**Update**

Like Walter mentioned in his comment, even though the function `foo` is the non void function and the one triggering the error, it is the function `throw_invalid` that needs the attribute. Setting `throw_invalid` as `noreturn` will tell the compiler that `foo` will also not return whenever the code path with the function `throw_invalid` is taken.

Comment: @Default The non-void function is `foo()`, and the compiler warns because it doesn't return a value. However, the end of this function can never be reached, because `throw_invalid()` never returns. The solution provided in this answer tells the compiler that fact, so that it can avoid the spurious warning.

Answer (score 3):

In my understanding, you need first make sure that your parameters are valid before doing any computation. Said that, I believe that your can overcome this issue just by rewritting your code accordingly

In your example, something like that:

```
int foo(const char * str)
{
   // Make sure that str is valid
   if( str == NULL ) throw_invalid();

   return 42;
}
```

Comment: This only works with the trivial example, but there are cases, there you cannot reorder your code in such a way (without making it less efficient or altering it otherwise).